# Why is my button in kotlin not working? (android studio)

Tags: android, kotlin

It just even won't recognise that. I am actually trying this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S4jkcRhembY

Here is my code in activitymain:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/requestpermissionbutonu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

And in mainactivity.kt here I use it like this:

```
requestpermissionbutonu.setOnClickListener {
            requestPermissions()
        }
```

It says this: `Unresolved reference: requestpermissionbutonu`

imports are fine aswell, as seen here:

```
package com.example.camlockotlin
import android.Manifest
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.util.Log
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast the Button from xml in Kotlin first :

```
val requestpermissionbutonu = findViewById<Button>(R.id.requestpermissionbutonu)
```

then you can set the OnClickListener

Answer (score 3):

You need this in your app module's `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

The code you're using relies on *Kotlin synthetic binding* which means magic that finds views for you and creates a variable you can refer to, without you needing to do anything. That's what the `kotlin-android-extensions` plugin does

Synthetics are deprecated now so you're not supposed to use them. @A Honey Bustard's answer is the best (and normal) way to handle it, with `findViewById`, unless you want to use the [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) library